# Resize image based on placement in content

Tags: javascript, css, image, css-float

I have a really weird request from a client:

Basically I have a blog post where in the beginning of the post there is a "meta data" box floated to the right. So in the beginning of the post the width for content is 300px and after the box ends, the width is 500px. SO the content wraps/flows around that box, like an L-shape.

The client wants that if an image is inserted into the post, that if it's below the box, it's 100% width (500px) and if it's next to the box, it should be 300px wide. Automatically. They do not want to resize the image themselves.

I cannot do this in backend (PHP), is it possible to do it in CSS /JS? The tricky part here is that I do not know where the image is in the content - it can be the first element in the content, it can be in the middle, in the end, whereever...

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understand the context enough, but this might get you in the right direction....

```
var offsetOfBottomOfBox = 700; //you would figure this out a different way

$("#contentDiv img").each(function(idx,el){
    //get image position in document
    var y = $(this).offset().top;

    if(y < offsetOfBottomOfBox) {
        $(this).css("width","300px");
    }
});
```

note: I have not tested this code...

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking kinda in the same direction as well. Guess this is the way to go, although it has it's limits (hard to make universal).